# Regex to remove (ISBN 88987321) from the string

Tags: regex, replace

What is the regex to remove (ISBN 8987983721) from the string, including ( and ) characters.
I'm trying to do it with Bilk Rename Utility but can not succeed.

I provided (ISBN [0-9]*)() and \1\2 but insted everything is removed from the string except ISBN but I need the opposite effect

Comment: Also note, that ISBNs aren't strictly numeric: The last digit (checksum) can also be `X`.

Comment: C# language. the number of strings with them is limited so only numbers are present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript:

```
string = string.replace(/\(ISBN [^)]+\)/g, '')
```

PHP:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\(ISBN [^)]+\)/', '', $string);
```

sed:

```
string=$(sed 's/(ISBN [^)]\+)//g' <<< "$string")
```

Ruby:

```
string = string.gsub(/\(ISBN [^)]+\)/, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove the ( and ):

```
(\(ISBN [0-9]*)\)
```

will give you the result with this test string:

```
Im testing to remove (ISBN 8987983721) from my string // Im testing to remove from my string
```

and depending on language you may want to use global replace so you remove all (ISBN xxxxx) texts